# Mouse Detect, OS Boot

Tags: operating-system, driver, bios

I was just wondering how the mouse, keyboard works during the boot process. Let us say that I have a USB mouse and a USB keyboard. When I switch on my computer, POST is done just to check whether all the hardware connected to my system are working. But to get a USB hardware working, we need to have a USB driver which ultimately is a process. But if OS is not loaded yet(I mean init and swapper processes), how this process comes into existence? One thing striking my mind is BIOS. But I think, BIOS can't identify the different drivers needed to detect different mouse, keyboards. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern BIOSes emulate the PS/2 ports 0x60 and 0x64 using [SMM/SMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode) with a feature often called "USB Legacy Support" (see the [EHCI specification](http://www.intel.com/technology/usb/download/ehci-r10.pdf) for more info.)

When the OS itself loads and initializes the USB controller there is a controller ownership transition from BIOS-owned to OS-owned.

Answer (score 3):

The BIOS is able to enumerate and control a certain subset of USB devices.  In particular, mice and keyboards belong to a common class of devices (Human Interface Devices, HID) that are have a common, defined interface and which is fairly to drive.  So, the BIOS just has drivers for that class of devices baked in.